# How to invoke GUI thread in VB.NET from SignalR Hub

Tags: vb.net, delegates, signalr, invoke

I have a problem concerning following piece of code (C#):

```
stockTickerHub.On("notify", () =>
Context.Post(delegate
{
    mainForm.textBox1.Text += "Notified!\n";
}, null)
);
```

Above code runs in an async Sub in a VB.NET Module. I am not allowed to access the Text-Property of textBox1. How does the above code look like in VB.NET?

I tried:

```
myHub.On(Of String, String)("addMessagea", _
            Sub(nam, param)
                mainForm.textBox1.Text = param.ToString()
                Console.WriteLine("Should have append '" + nam.ToString() + param.ToString() + "'")
            End Sub)
```

SignalR is a framework released by Microsoft.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it run in a module? Could it run from the mainform?

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple forms should have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Invoke method on the control. It will make sure that the delegate you supply is invoked on the main thread.

This is one of the reasons why WPF is nicer to work with, when you data-bind and `NotifyPropertyChanged` triggers the framework will fix that for you